# Unable to show debug messages ILogger.LogDebug and how to enable for Serilog

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

Using ILogger interface I am unable to see any output from `LogDebug` even when I have set:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
}
```

And I use to register:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .MinimumLevel.Information()
                            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .WriteTo.Console()
                            .WriteTo.File("logging.log")
                            .CreateLogger();

    var host = CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.Configure<HostOptions>(option =>
                        {
                            option.ShutdownTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                        });

                        services.AddLogging();
                        // services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

                        services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
                        {
                            // Hooks hosted services into the Generic Host pipeline while resolving them through Simple Injector
                            options.AddHostedService<Worker>();

                            // Allows injection of ILogger & IStringLocalizer dependencies into application components
                            options.AddLogging();
                            // options.AddLocalization();
                        });
                    })
                    .Build()
                    .UseSimpleInjector(container);


    config.Build();
    host.Run(); 
}


public static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

    builder
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
            if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() == true)
                logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configApp) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        })
        .UseConsoleLifetime();

    return builder;
}
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong please or missing?

I am now planning to use Serilog for all my logging and for legacy libs to use the ILogger interface, anything that i would need to change to enable (or remove any conflicting settings)?

Comment: I don't see that you have [setup your LoggerConfiguration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/README.md)

Comment: Apologies, well spotted, have added what i have in Main()